# HID usb device - sending and receiving data

Tags: android, usb, hid

I want to get data from antenna connected to android device via otg cable. I have already establish connection an pick proper endpoints to send and receive data. The problem is with communication, i have to send 65 bytes of data, but the endpoints allow only 64, and when i try to send 65 it get stuck after 1/2 sending/reading requests.

```
private lateinit var connection: UsbDeviceConnection
private lateinit var usbEndpointZero: UsbEndpoint
private lateinit var usbEndpointOne: UsbEndpoint

override fun sendUsbPacket(data: ByteArray): Boolean {
    synchronized(connection) {
        connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, FORCE_INTERFACE)
        val value = connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOne, data, data.size/*usbEndpointOne.maxPacketSize*/, 0)
        connection.releaseInterface(usbInterface)
        return viewModel.getDeviceConnectedObservable().value ?: false
    }
}


override fun receiveUsbPacket(data: ByteArray): Boolean {
    synchronized(connection) {
        connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, FORCE_INTERFACE)
        val value = connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointZero, data, data.size/*usbEndpointZero.maxPacketSize*/, 0)
        connection.releaseInterface(usbInterface)
        return viewModel.getDeviceConnectedObservable().value ?: false
    }
}
```

What should do i do to be able to send 65 bytes data and receive response same length? I can not use eg. https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial because my usb device is not supported.

Comment: Till someone answers your query, please try sending/reading a zero length transfer. Some devices need Zero Length packet to mark end of a transaction.

Comment: Thanks Shaibal, i will check it in friday, and let you know if it works.

Comment: Shaibal, unfortunately its not working for me. Just get stuck again after 2/3 tries.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation..